# VSCode Django Virtualenvwrapper

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, virtualenvwrapper

Hi i have my django project with use Virtualenvwrapper.
I use VSCode and works for me workon etc in terminal.
I have 3 files settings to run project in local server and in VPS server.
I remove from settings my SECRET_KEY and all files with codes to json files.
and run project like this:
workon env_name
(env_name) workon my_project
python manage.py runserver --settings setings.local2
and this works good with file like this:
like this:

```
from my_project.settings import *
import json
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
with open('keys_my_project.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

SECRET_KEY = config['SECRET_KEY']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config['NAME'],
        'USER': config['USER'],
        'PASSWORD': config['PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': config['HOST'],
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and now i have a problem with using VSCode debbuger:

```
        {
        "name": "my_project django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "my_project/manage.py",
        "args": ["runserver --settings settings.local2"],
        "django": true
    }
```

MY ERROR:

```
Exception has occurred: ImproperlyConfigured
The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
  File "my_project\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "my_project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
```

**why my VSCode debbuger dont read json in settings file ?**

ps. my manage.py

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_settings.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
"args": ["runserver --settings settings.local2"],
```

To:

```
"args": ["runserver", "--settings settings.local2"],
```

Comment: Its dont work ;/ its only work if im override my manage.py to debbuger.py : imports from settings.local2 import DEBUG  and then     if DEBUG == True:
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings.local2') but i dont like this way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the typo in your question (--settings setings.local2) isn't lurking somewhere in your code, I'm not sure your exact issue. However, if you don't mind an alternative suggestion, I recommend making use of vscode's built-in capacity for handling environment variables. It goes along the lines of

```
    {
        "name": "my_project django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/my_project/manage.py",
        "env": {
            "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "my_project.config.settings",
            "NAME": "Johnny",
            "SECRET_KEY": "foo",
            .... and so forth....
        }
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload",
            "--nothreading"
        ],
        "django": true
    }
```

You can also use a `.env` file:

```
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

Then you would call these in `settings.py` using `os`

```
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'foo')
```

Also note the use of `${workspaceFolder}` and `--nothreading`, it might even be worth playing with these and seeing what happens before you refactor.